# Recommended software to scan and OCR documents and receipts on PC

Tags: windows, pdf, ocr

I'm trying to keep my receipts and other important documents in digital form (as searchable PDFs). For many years I've been using an old copy of Acrobat CS2 which came with my iMac many moons ago and right now this is the only reason why I have this clunker around.

I'm curious what other people are using these days to (hopefully easily) convert paper into searchable PDFs. Spending several hundred dollars on an Acrobat upgrade (or committing to a monthly tithe via a subscription) doesn't get me super-excited.

Comment: Websearching "free OCR PDF" finds a number of tools for that purpose. I forget the name of the (non-web-based) one I used most recently, but it was free for personal use and seemed to work fairly well -- better for single pages than for multiple, though.

Comment: See [OCR tools on Windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10266/903) if you're on Windows.